# Python float vs numpy.float32

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Using `numpy.float32`.

```
t = numpy.float32(.3)
x = numpy.float32(1)
r = numpy.float32(-.3)
_t = t+x+r
_t == 1 # -> False
```

Using regular Python `float`.

```
t = .3
x = 1
r = -.3
_t = t+x+r
_t == 1 # -> True
```

Why?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: You don't need to make a `np.float32` object directly.  Make a multiitem array.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point values are inherently non-exact on computers. The python default `float` is a what's called a double precision floating point number on most machines according to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html. `numpy.float32` is a single precision float. It's double precision counterpart is `numpy.float64`. This could explain the difference in this case.

In general floating point numbers shouldn't be compared directly using `==`. You can use `numpy.isclose` to deal with the small errors caused by non-exact floating point representations.

Answer (score 2):

Python float is a C double type: [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric):

> Floating point numbers are usually implemented using **double** in C; information about the precision and internal representation of floating point numbers for the machine on which your program is running is available in `sys.float_info`.

Therefore, you are comparing 32 and 64 precision floating point numbers. The following will work:

```
t = numpy.float64(.3)
x = numpy.float64(1)
r = numpy.float64(-.3)
_t = t+x+r
_t == 1
```